# How do square brackets determine the class in angular 2

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I was just going through an Angular 4.0 component online on the [ngx GitHub repo](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/blob/master/src/app/%40theme/components/header/header.component.html#L2), basically just the header component as can be seen below:

```
<div class="header-container"
     [class.left]="position === 'normal'"
     [class.right]="position === 'inverse'">
  <div class="logo-containter">
    <a (click)="toggleSidebar()" href="#" class="navigation"><i class="nb-menu"></i></a>
    <div class="logo" (click)="goToHome()">ngx-<span>admin</span></div>
  </div>
  <ngx-theme-switcher></ngx-theme-switcher>
</div>
```

The thing is i am not quite able to understand the way the `class` code works , i see the below code and am not quite able to understand it:

```
[class.left]="position === 'normal'"
[class.right]="position === 'inverse'"
```

What exactly does the code above really do ?

The typescript file for the header component looks like so:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { NbMenuService, NbSidebarService } from '@nebular/theme';
import { UserService } from '../../../@core/data/users.service';
import { AnalyticsService } from '../../../@core/utils/analytics.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-header',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input() position = 'normal';

  user: any;

  userMenu = [{ title: 'Profile' }, { title: 'Log out' }];

  constructor(private sidebarService: NbSidebarService,
              private menuService: NbMenuService,
              private userService: UserService,
              private analyticsService: AnalyticsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe((users: any) => this.user = users.nick);
  }

  toggleSidebar(): boolean {
    this.sidebarService.toggle(true, 'menu-sidebar');
    return false;
  }

  toggleSettings(): boolean {
    this.sidebarService.toggle(false, 'settings-sidebar');
    return false;
  }

  goToHome() {
    this.menuService.navigateHome();
  }

  startSearch() {
    this.analyticsService.trackEvent('startSearch');
  }
}
```

Comment: @Igor actually not a tutorial , --> https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/blob/master/src/app/%40theme/components/header/header.component.html#L2

Comment: I had to do some digging but found the documentation in the Template Syntax. Btw I upvoted, I thought it was a fair question given that the answer was not very easy to find.

Comment: @Igor Thank you for taking the trouble man ! thanks alot :) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is short hand syntax to apply a conditional css class to an element.

```
[class.left]="position === 'normal'"
```

Would apply the css class `left` to the element if the `position === 'normal'` evaluates to `truthy` and otherwise it would not apply the class.

See the [Template syntax documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding) as a reference.

Also here the syntax [documentation from the cheat sheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet)

> ```
> <div [class.extra-sparkle]="isDelightful">
> ```
>
> Binds the presence of the CSS class extra-sparkle on the element to the truthiness of the expression `isDelightful`